# How to validate a RadioGroup with yup in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, headless-ui

I'm using headless/ui to create a Radio Group in my form submission and using yup to validate the form. I cannot register the radio group using the usual `{...register("radio-group")}` so my radio group isn't part of the form validation anymore.

If I add the `{...register("radio-group")}` it gives me this error in console

```
not be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

**yup schema**

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
...
 radioGroup: yup.string().onOf(["foo","bar"]).required("required")
})
```

**form**

```
<form
 onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
 name="form"
>
 <div className="col-span-3">
  <RadioOptions -> This is a react component implementing a headless/ui RadioGroup
   label="Radio Group"
   options={["foo","bar"]}
   handleUpdatedSelection={(selection) => {setRadioGroup(selection)}}
  />
 </div>
</form>
```

What I'm currently doing right now to get this done is just to remove the radio group from the yup schema and set the data during onSubmit. But it would be nice to have this part of the yup schema just so it doesn't feel hacky.